# ! ERROR Could not load "versions.yml" from config bucket:

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

#### Issue Summary:

Used a Halyard Docker Container to install Spinnaker

```
docker run -p 8084:8084 -p 9000:9000 \
    --name halyard --rm \
    -v ~/.hal:/home/spinnaker/.hal \
    -v ~/.kube/config:/home/spinnaker/.kube/config \
    -e http_proxy=<corporate proxy>:<port> \
    -e https_proxy=<corporate proxy>:<port> \
    -e DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Dhttps.proxyHost=<corporate proxy> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<port> -Dhttp.proxyHost=<corporate proxy> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port>" \
    -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttps.proxyHost=<corporate proxy> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<port> -Dhttp.proxyHost=<corporate proxy> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port>" \
    -d \
    us-docker.pkg.dev/spinnaker-community/docker/halyard:stable
```

Exec into the container, then ran the below command.

```
bash-5.0$ hal version list
+ Get current deployment
  Success
+ Get Spinnaker version
  Success
- Get released versions
  Failure
Validation in Global:
! ERROR Could not load "versions.yml" from config bucket:
  http://<corporate-proxy>.

- Failed to load available Spinnaker versions.
```

#### Cloud Provider(s):

Bare-Metal Kubernetes On-Premise

I am trying to install Spinnaker behind a corporate proxy in the On-Prem Infrastructure. There seems to be an issue with the proxy setup. I read lot of articles online/SO , yet stuck.
Please let me know if more info is needed, I will add more details.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? I'm facing the same

Comment: not yet, bro. I am thinking of duplicating the spinnaker repo to local then referring to it in BOM. Maybe that will help. I will try and let know here.

Comment: I'm doing the same and getting packer.tar.gz not found error. Where can I find that file?